# Is there a way in Danfo.js to change the value of a single cell?

Tags: javascript, pandas, danfojs

I understood Danfo.js is the Javascript equivalent to Pandas. Now I have a Danfo dataframe and want to change the cell at row **i** and column **"name"**. In pandas I would use

```
df.at(i,'name') = new_value
```

However with Danfo I get `cannot assign to function call`. Is there a way to to this ?

Comment: Side note, but those `()` would actually be `[]` in pandas.

Comment: Try `let cell = df.loc({ rows: [i], columns: ["Name"] })`

Comment: @Nick This just lets me read the cell value, right? But I want to change the value.

Comment: @PhilipZ. Seems like you can't do this yet in Danfo , see this issue : https://github.com/javascriptdata/danfojs/issues/127

Answer (score 1):

You can access and modify the underlying array using `df.values`.

```
let json = [{
    fruit: "peach",
    rating: 10,
}, {
    fruit: "blueberry",
    rating: 9,
}];

let df = new danfo.DataFrame(json);
df.print();
```

```
╔════════════╤═══════════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║            │ fruit             │ rating            ║
╟────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ 0          │ peach             │ 10                ║
╟────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ 1          │ blueberry         │ 9                 ║
╚════════════╧═══════════════════╧═══════════════════╝
```

```
df.values[0][1] = 9000; // modify row 0, col 1 (rating)
df.print();
```

```
╔════════════╤═══════════════════╤═══════════════════╗
║            │ fruit             │ rating            ║
╟────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ 0          │ peach             │ 9000              ║
╟────────────┼───────────────────┼───────────────────╢
║ 1          │ blueberry         │ 9                 ║
╚════════════╧═══════════════════╧═══════════════════╝
```

TypeScript will complain at the array indexing but `as any` will suppress it.

```
((df.values[0] as any)[1] as any) = 9000;
```